# How to configure FreeRADIUS with multiple ldap servers?

Tags: ldap, ubuntu-12.04, openldap, samba, freeradius

I have a FreeRADIUS server that uses ldap as as a storage backend for its users. They are both located on the same machine running UBUNTU Linux 12.04 LTS.

Now I would like to set up another ldap server on another machine to add redundancy so that I could use it in case of my local ldap server's failure. Can anyone tell me how I can do it? Nothing is mentioned in RADIUS configuration files regarding multiple ldap servers.

The same question applies to Samba.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually pretty easy, you can just list multiple servers here [in the LDAP configuration](https://github.com/FreeRADIUS/freeradius-server/blob/v2.x.x/raddb/modules/ldap#L33), separated by commas.

libldap takes care of the rest.

Edit: For later versions of FreeRADIUS 3 the LDAP module expects multiple instances of the `server` config item. For example:

```
server = 'ldap1.example.org'
server = 'ldap2.example.org'
server = 'ldap3.example.org'
```

This is so internally, when the module is rewriting the URIs, they're already broken out into separate strings, which makes the code easier. It also looks a bit cleaner.

Comment: According to the docs this isn't the correct way to set up failover over multiple servers.

Comment: I wrote the rlm_ldap module distributed with FreeRADIUS version 3.  OpenLDAP's libldap will accept multiple servers and will failover between them just fine.  This mechanism is more efficient as it doesn't require repeatedly calling instances of rlm_ldap just to have them fail. `redundant {}` and `redundant-load-balance {}` have no state beyond the current request, and no way to determine the current state of the upstream connection.